# Images across an amazon AWS instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

So i'm new to amazon aws after many days configuring and tweaking stuff, i still have a major question that i can't answer.

I need to deploy multiple prestashop websites. So i created an instance based on centos IAM and i configure it to run mysql Database and ispconfig. Now the reason why i chose AWS is for scalability.

So, i chose c3.large and now in the volumes i have a 8Go for the instance and 22 attached volume but empty.
The question is :

- If i add a website, should the website files and data be stored in an
  amazon S3 ? If yes, what my 22Go SSD is for ?
- How to tell centos that i will store the website in an s3 and how to do it ?
- when i'll launch for example 4 instances for load balance, how these instances will find the website static content like images, etc. if they are stored in a separated s3 ? Will it replicate the whole website ? If when i launch a new instance it replicate the whole thing, including the website, then will it be synchronized while people buy items or i add products ?
  Does this mean that if i have a 50Go website, for each instance i'll have a 50 more Go to pay for ?

I know these are weird questions, but i'm totally lost and the amazon documentation is SO general they never give you the whole picture in one tutorial.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Data will never be stored in S3 until you explicitly do so. You need to make explicit calls to S3 to store data in S3. S3 is not available as additional disks to your servers. What you are talking about here could be [EBS](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/). EBS blocks resemble the typical disk volumes that you can mount/unmount.
- Not Applicable
- Again, if you are going to have your data in EBS attached to your server and your web-server is serving content from here, it is like any other standalone server with multiple disk volumes. You can map directories to volume as you would otherwise do in a CentOS backed linux machine. **S3** - You will have to explicitly add content to S3 via S3 calls. Each static resource gets a unique url (key) and you can reference that in your code (html etc.) So, static content served from S3 can be made independent of server load-balancer.

You can use the load-balancer ELB to load balance between multiple servers. The synchronization mechanism would still be your responsibility and would depend on how you maintain sessions etc.

In any case, I would recommend you to start with micro instances, try and then go for instances with richer hardware.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When a create a new instance, is the volumes attached to the main instance is duplicated, or i have to create a new ebs volume from current volume snapshot to attach it to the new instance? Thanks

Comment: If you want your additional servers to be the replica of your 1st server, you can create an AMI (image) of your server and then launch the other servers using this image. Please check [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-launch-snapshot.html). This is in case I got your question right.